# Expecting external language error in PL/SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors, package, syntax-error

Hello I'm writing a data conversion function, but it seems as if I'm getting a syntax error that I cannot figure out for the life of me. Also, if you see any errors or improvements I can make in my code please let me know. The error I get is `FOUND V_GMIN expecting: EXTERNAL LANGUAGE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_user_info
IS

  function get_gmin(i_user_id IN EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    V_GMIN EZ01USERMAST.GMIN;
  BEGIN

    select GMIN 
     into V_GMIN
     from EZ01USERMAST
    where user_id= i_user_id
     and rownum = 1;

    return V_GMIN;

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    return null; 
  END get_gmin;

 end pkg_user;
 /
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also if you are really meaning to create a package and not just a function a package consists of 2 parts, a specification and a body.  And the name you give in your end statement is different from the name in the create statement at the top.  I took the liberty of editing the code so the select is in it's own anonymous block and any exception gets raised.  Still could use better error handling but I'll leave that up to you.  As a rule try to return from one place too.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_user_info AS
  function get_gmin(i_user_id IN EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID%TYPE) RETURN EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID%TYPE;
END pkg_user_info;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_user_info AS
  function get_gmin(i_user_id IN EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID%TYPE) RETURN EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID%TYPE IS

    V_GMIN EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID%TYPE := NULL;

    BEGIN
      BEGIN 
        select GMIN 
        into V_GMIN
        from EZ01USERMAST
        where user_id = i_user_id
        and rownum = 1;
      EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
          RAISE;
      END;
      RETURN V_GMIN;

   END get_gmin;

END pkg_user_info;
/
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, for some odd reason this script is compiling with errors. Great start though, I'll look into it

Comment: Sorry to bug you again. When I write this function as an anonymous block everything works fine but for some reason when I include this function as part of a package that's when i run into the same error? any clue why that may be?

Comment: @Jules - Hmm.  Is there more to the package example that you are not showing?  I wonder if the error is caused by unseen code?  Is the error thrown at compile-time or at run-time? Please include the exact error text. Is GMIN the same datatype as EZ01USERMAST.USER_ID?

Comment: @Jules - Wait are you copying and pasting my code as it appears in the window above?  If so let me add the slashes after the separate create statements so they run in the right order.  That could be it.

Comment: I fixed the issue gary, just some cleanup I had to do. Thanks for your help budd

Comment: You bet but please let us know what the problem was so others can learn from it.

Comment: For sure. The problem to begin was I wasn't formatting my PL/SQL block correctly you came along and helped me with that. The second issue is that I was mapping to columns that weren't created yet,

Answer (score 2):

Here are some style and syntax tips:

- WHEN OTHERS THEN return null; This just swallows any and all errors that might occur.  It can cause hours of painful debugging. Try

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    --log the error with an autonomous transaction logging package
    RAISE;
  END;
- V_GMIN EZ01USERMAST.GMIN;  what is a EZ01USERMAST.GMIN?  do you mean EZ01USERMAST.GMIN%type  ?
- why do you add and rownum =1 when you are selecting a user_id? If I had two users with the same ID I would want to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you forgot to put in the keyword BODY in the package declaration of the body. The compiler expected a specification declaration here.